# Excel formula to count unique text values in a column not working as expected

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2016

---

*UPDATE: I just realized that this is only counting UNIQUE entries as in there is only 1, whereas I am looking to count all UNIQUE entries whether it be 1 or duplicated.*

The term is DISTINCT that I needed.

---

What is incorrect about the formula for counting unique text values?

All examples I have found state this is how to calculate the total unique entries in a spreadsheet.

In this example you can see it is NOT calculating correctly for the formula.

```
=SUM(IF(ISTEXT(A1:A8)*COUNTIF(A1:A8,A1:A8)=1,1,0))
```

*Yes, I am pressing CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER*

[image: 6 should be the count]

Comment: Why do you expect that to work? It's counting only values which occur precisely once, and so excludes d and f, which both appear twice. Perhaps confirm your Excel version so that we can provide you with a correct solution.

Comment: @JosWoolley Excel 2016. I just realized as well it is only counting where the value is 1 time. I'm looking to just find all unique values in the sense that it is different from the others which is why I was expecting a count of 6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you use the `UNIQUE()` function for that?
This should work:

```
=COUNTA(UNIQUE(A1:A8))
```

If you don't have the `UNIQUE()` function, you might opt for this:

```
=SUM(1/COUNTIF(A$1:A$8,A1:A8))
```

It's in fact quite silly: when you have a letter once, you get 1. When you have it twice, you get 2, ..., by dividing one by that number and adding all of them, you get the number you're looking for.

Comment: Sadly, in Excel 2016 that does not exist. But thank you for the response.

Comment: @edjm: what do you think about my second formula? (I'm actually quite proud of it) :-)

Comment: Actually that 2nd one does work for me as in =SUM(1/COUNTIF(A1:A8,A1:A8)) and pressing CTRL SHIFT ENTER

Comment: `SUMPRODUCT()` would keep users from having to CSE the formula =)

Comment: @JvdV: I don't Ctrl+Shift+ENTER, the formula just works as is (but I'm working with the latest version of Excel, which might explain this.

Comment: Yes, the latest versions of Excel don't need CSE-entering, but OP's 2016 versions still does.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following:
`=SUM(1/(COUNTIF(A1:A8,A1:A8))` to get the count of uniques.

Or if the range includes blanks:
`=SUM(IFERROR(1/COUNTIF(A1:A9,A1:A9),0))`

Older Excel versions require both to be entered with `ctrl+shift+enter`

Or I think this doesn't require `ctrl+shift+enter`:

`=SUMPRODUCT(N(FREQUENCY(IFERROR(MATCH(A1:A8,A1:A80,0),0),ROW(A1:A8))>0))`

In Office 365 the UNIQUE function can be used, for instance:

`=LET(range,A1:A8,flt,FILTER(range,range<>"",""),IF(flt="",0,COUNTA(UNIQUE(flt))))`

Comment: yes it is with ctrl+shift+enter

Comment: Thanks, updated it and posted some alternate solutions.

Answer (score 2):

For `Excel 2016`:

`=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(MATCH(A1:A8,A1:A8,0),ROW(A1:A8)-MIN(ROW(A1:A8))+1),1))`

If you need the `ISTEXT` condition:

`=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF(ISTEXT(A1:A8),MATCH(A1:A8,A1:A8,0)),ROW(A1:A8)-MIN(ROW(A1:A8))+1),1))`

Comment: I was running into an issue where I had too many arguments. The other posting was much easier to implement. But thank you.

Comment: Just know that the reciprocal `COUNTIF`/`SUM` set-up is much slower over large ranges.